# File doesn't get hosted

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to save in a repository just .json files. My idea was to be able to access these files with the url that GitHub pages provides. I would like it to show just like this user:

This is his github repository:

https://github.com/LearnWebCode/json-example

and this is the Github pages of one of the json, for example:

https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-2.json

The problem I have is that when I make the github pages, my page doesn't load and I must be doing something wrong.

This is my repository:

https://github.com/JuanmaRuizF/JSON-DAW1

And this is where it should be shown:

https://juanmaruizf.github.io/JSON-DAW1/comentarios.json

Answer (score 1):

In both instances, ([`animals-2.json`](https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-2.json) or your [`comentarios.json`](https://juanmaruizf.github.io/JSON-DAW1/comentarios.json)) the JSON file is display by the browser (Firefox or Chrome)

If this is not working in your browser, try the raw URL:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuanmaRuizF/JSON-DAW1/main/comentarios.json